# Python: How to dump data from a log file to different files for different dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

Logs generated from a software are dumped in the below manner -

```
 2:41:04 Start-Date: Thu May 26 2022 02:41:04 MDT
 2:42:50 check in 
 2:42:50 check in
 2:42:50 check in
 8:53:42 check out
 8:53:42 check in
 8:53:43 check in
 8:53:43 check out
 23:59:54 check in
 23:59:55 check out
 23:59:55 check out
 00:11:23 check in
 00:11:25 check in
 00:13:34 check out
```

I want to extract data in such a way that the script gets the date from the log, pulls the data for a single day i.e. will time < 24:00:00, and then dumps this data in a file. Then extracts the data for the next day when the time resets and dumps the data in another file.

For eg. It should created a text file 260522.txt containing below data -

```
2:42:50 check in
2:42:50 check in
8:53:42 check out
8:53:42 check in
8:53:43 check in
8:53:43 check out
23:59:54 check in
23:59:55 check out
23:59:55 check out
```

And create another file 27May2022.txt containing -

```
00:11:25 check in
00:13:34 check out
```

Comment: Is there a start date to consider for the first entry in the file?, as there is no date information in the file, there's only time.

Comment: Yes, at the start. Have updated the logs above.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code. You could at least to read line-by-line and compare time in lines. If new line has hour smaller then previous line then it should go to new file with next date (or next number) in filename. So you have to keep previous time in one variable and current time in other variable, compare it and later move current to previuos, and read next line. It need also to keep current date or number and increase it when you get smaller hour.

Comment: You can extract the start date from the first line and convert it to a python date object and use that as the start date for the logs. Next do what @furas suggested and increment the date object by a day each time you detect a change in the day by comparing subsequent entries. When the change in day is detected increment the date object and write the collected log entries up to that point with the new date as the file name. Repeat till the end of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read only first line, split into `time`, `text`, `date` and convert `date` to object `datetime`. Get `hour` from `time` as prevous hour to compare it with hour in next line

Next use loop to read next lines. Read line, get current hour from this line and compare with previous hour, if current hour is smaller then you have new day and you have to increase object `datetime` to get next date, and create new filename. Later you can write current line in file. And finally get current hour as previous hour to compare it with next line.

---

Full working example:

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and run code. But you should use `open()`

```
text = '''2:41:04 Start-Date: Thu May 26 2022 02:41:04 MDT
2:42:50 check in 
2:42:50 check in
2:42:50 check in
8:53:42 check out
8:53:42 check in
8:53:43 check in
8:53:43 check out
23:59:54 check in
23:59:55 check out
23:59:55 check out
00:11:23 check in
00:11:25 check in
00:13:34 check out'''

import io
import datetime

#with open('filename.txt') as fh:
with io.StringIO(text) as fh:
    
    # --- first line ---

    first_line = fh.readline().strip()
    
    time, text, date = first_line.split(" ", 2)
    
    print('time:', time)
    print('text:', text)
    print('date:', date)

    # convert string `date` to object `datetime`
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S MDT')
    print('dt:', dt)

    # create filename for first file
    filename = dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y.txt')
    print('filename:', filename)

    # get hour to compare with next line
    previous_hour = int(time.split(':', 1)[0])
    #print('previous_hour:', previous_hour)
    
    # --- next lines ---

    for line in fh:
        # get hour to compare with previus hour
        current_hour = int(line.split(':', 1)[0])
        
        # compare hours and increase date, and create filename with new date
        if current_hour < previous_hour:
            dt += datetime.timedelta(days=1)       # get next date
            filename = dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y.txt') # get new filename
            print('filename:', filename)
        
        # write line in file    
        with open(filename, 'w') as output:
            output.write(line)
            
        # assign current to previous to compare it with next line
        previous_hour = current_hour
```